# if else combined with df.shift()

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement

I have hourly frequency prices and am trying to perform a naive forecast where x = xt-168 if Day of Week = 1,6,7 and x = xt-24 otherwise. To do this, I am using if, else combined with the shift() command on my pandas dataframe.

```
                     Price_REG1  Price_REG2  ...  Day of Week  Hour of Day
date                                         ...                          
2020-01-01 00:00:00       30.83       30.83  ...            3            1
2020-01-01 01:00:00       28.78       28.78  ...            3            2
2020-01-01 02:00:00       28.45       28.45  ...            3            3
2020-01-01 03:00:00       27.90       27.90  ...            3            4
2020-01-01 04:00:00       27.52       27.52  ...            3            5
                        ...         ...  ...          ...          ...
2021-12-31 19:00:00       50.21       50.21  ...            5           20
2021-12-31 20:00:00       48.01       48.01  ...            5           21
2021-12-31 21:00:00       33.96       33.96  ...            5           22
2021-12-31 22:00:00       33.08       33.08  ...            5           23
2021-12-31 23:00:00       32.34       32.34  ...            5           24
```

```
if df['Day of Week'].any() == 1 | df['Day of Week'].any() == 6 | df['Day of Week'].any() == 7:
    df.shift(168)
else:
    df.shift(24)
```

This doesn't give any Errors, but also, nothing is happening to my df.

Comment: `df = df.shift(...)`, it's not an in-place method

Comment: I used it before to shift my entire dataframe e.g. df_24 = df.shift(24). So I assumed I could use it here too to apply two different shifts?

Comment: You are not assigning the outcome of the shift to any variable. It will be disposed of by the garbage collector

Comment: `df.shift` makes a shifted **copy** of the dataframe. You are not doing anything with the copy currently, so it is deleted immediately.

Comment: Oh. I see, sorry for such a dumb question..